# Php-gpg not working for email encryption

Tags: php, email, encryption, pgp

I am using the [github php-gpg](https://github.com/jasonhinkle/php-gpg) library to encrypt HIPAA data from a form to send to an email client which has a keyring.

In Thunderbird I am receiving a fail message: "gpg: decryption failed: No secret key."  However, it appears Thunderbird can identify the block's public key.

I have tested the key and it runs smoothly if I send directly using Enigmail encryption or Claws-Mail.  I can take the Enigmail-created PGP message, add it to my PHP to mail, and it will decrypt correctly so it's not headers or plain-text issues.

I do not have the option to install directly on the server or I would use other PHP encryption options like *GnuPG* (not already there).  A local install of PEAR so I could try the *phpseclib* also didn't work out.

Does anyone have any experience with this github php-gpg library and have it working?  If so, I am following the usage exactly with a key that I know works.  Please let me know what to look for with this -- because in my troubleshooting it keeps coming down to the block encrypted with the library that seems to be failing decryption.

My current code:

```
require_once 'libs/GPG.php';
$gpg = new GPG();
$key = "//public key block is here...";
$pub_key = new GPG_Public_Key($key);
$plain_text = "text to encrypt";
$encrypted = $gpg->encrypt($pub_key,$plain_text);
...
mail($to, $subject, $encrypted, $headers);
```

Comment: did you already test with the latest master version?